# Jenkins Pipeline plugin seemingly skipping commands

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a [Jenkins Pipeline plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) script looking like this:

```
stage("check out project") {
    shell "pwd"
    echo "test 1"
    git credentialsId: "user", url: "http://url/project"
    echo "test 2"
    shell "git --version"
    echo "test 3"
}
```

The output of the build is this:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (check out project)
[Pipeline] echo
test 1
[Pipeline] echo
test 2
[Pipeline] echo
test 3
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Judging from the output and the build time only the echo commands are executed. All others are ignored. No error seems to occur.

How can I get all commands to be executed?

Comment: Did you check the workspace to see if there was a git clone/pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script ran successfully and worked as expected after

1. surrounding it with `node{ }` and
2. using `sh` intead of `shell`

like this:

```
node{
    stage("check out project") {
        sh "pwd"
        echo "test 1"
        git credentialsId: '12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234', url: "git@github.com:sendgrid/sendgrid-java.git"
        echo "test 2"
        sh "git --version"
        echo "test 3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `sh` command really did help, but Git is still not working. :-(

Comment: It seems that `git` isn't working because we are using a too new Version of the Pipeline plugin (2.3) and a too old version of the Git plugin (2.4.4): https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35247